# SQL Join...Issue with joins

Tags: sql

I need help regarding SQL joins, i am trying join two tables as shown in below images

[image: Customer]

[image: Contacts]

[image: Result]

Comment: Most people here want sample table data and expected result as formatted text, not as images (or links to images.)

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. This site requires the code/data you're having trouble with to be part of the question, and **not** contained with images. Please have a read of the [help] and the [ask] in particular

Comment: you can join your customer table twice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you can try the below query to get the desired result -

```
SELECT CASE WHEN CT.partner2 IS NULL
                 THEN C.partner_id
            ELSE CT.partner1
       END Partner1,
       CT.partner2,
       C.Type,
       C.Company_name,
       C.First_name,
       CT.city,
       CT.Phone,
       CT.Email
  FROM CUSTOMER C
  LEFT JOIN CONTACTS CT ON C.partner_id = CT.partner2
```